# JUnit test failure while comparing two similar xml files

Tags: java, encoding, junit, dbunit

I tried to realise test with dbunit but I have a failure.

To sum up

- I have an import xml file for my fake database, *inputFlatXmlDataSet.xml* and
- I generate an export file *outputFlatXmlDataSet.xml*
- the final test is to ensure that both files are equals

But they aren't. There no difference to a naked eye, even diff with eclipse or notepad++ don't show anything.

I followed this tutorial : http://www.scub-foundation.org/accueil/tutoriaux/tutorial-dbunit/

I warn you it's a french tutorial, I suspect the encoding of the second file isn't UTF-8,
but I didn't manage to force the writing in UTF-8.

All the files and the code are the same than in the tutorial except *TestDBUnit.java*.
Here's the code :

```
 public void testExportData() throws Exception {
    // On récupère le jeu de données du fichier XML
    IDataSet dataSet = getDatabaseDataSet();

    // Fichier XML du jeu de données d'import
    File inputFile = new File(INPUT_DATA_SET_FILENAME);
    // On vérifie que le fichier existe
    assertNotNull(inputFile);
    // Fichier XML du jeu de données d'export
    File outputFile = new File(OUTPUT_DATA_SET_FILENAME);
    FileOutputStream(outputFile), "UTF-8")));
    FlatXmlDataSet.write(dataSet, new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(outputFile), "UTF-8"));
    // On compare les deux fichiers XML pour vérifier qu'ils sont identiques
    String inputDataSetString = FileUtils.readFileToString(inputFile/*,
            "UTF-8"*/).replace("  ", "\t").trim();
    String outputDataSetString = FileUtils.readFileToString(outputFile/*,
            "UTF-8"*/).replace("  ", "\t").trim();
    assertEquals(inputDataSetString, outputDataSetString);//The failure
```

I just add an `OutputStreamWriter` as Wrapper to force the encoding but it didn't change anything.

If you want any further details please do not hesitate.

Comment: What's `FileUtils`? Is it from Apache commons-io?

Comment: Have you tried to output `inputDataSetString` and `outputDataSetString` and then compare them?

Comment: If possible, please post these two XML files. It would be better to use http://xmlunit.sourceforge.net/ to compare XML files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using string equality to compare XML files is unwise, unless you are testing an XML-generation library and care about pretty printing.

In all other cases, you probably care about the *semantic* equality of the two files (i.e. *do they contain the same data?*). To aid with such a comparison, consider using [XMLUnit](http://xmlunit.sourceforge.net). This will compare the contents of your files, without worrying about whitespace or encoding.